# get formated output from mysql via python

Tags: python, mysql, format

Hi I want the following output from my query:

```
OK|Abortedclients=119063 Aborted_connects=67591 Binlog_cache_disk_use=0
```

But I dont know how to generate it. this is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "...", user="...", passwd="...")
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("SHOW GLOBAL STATUS")
rs = cursor.fetchall ()
#print rs
print "OK|"
for row in rs:
    print "%s=%s" % (row[0], row[1])
cursor.close()
```

this is what I get now:

```
OK|
Aborted_clients=119063
Aborted_connects=67591
Binlog_cache_disk_use=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Build the string using [join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print('OK|'+' '.join(['{0}={1}'.format(*row) for row in rs]))
```

`' '.join(iterable)` creates a string out of the strings in iterable, joined together with a space `' '` in between the strings.

---

To fix the code you posted with minimal changes, you could add a comma at the end of the print statements:

```
print "OK|",
for row in rs:
    print "%s=%s" % (row[0], row[1]),
```

This suppresses the automatic addition of a newline after each print statement.
It does, however, add a space (which is not what you said you wanted):

```
OK| Aborted_clients=0 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the rows together in one string:

```
output = []
for row in rs:
   output.append('%s=%s' % (row[0], row[1])

print ''.join(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Join each pair with '=' and then each result with ' ', appended to 'OK|':

```
'OK|' + (' '.join(['='.join(r) for r in rs]))
```